# Is there a term for this use of an indirect object?

Tags: english, terminology, sentences, grammatical-object

I have noticed that some Americans from the mid-South will use indirect objects in their speech where standard English would use a prepositional phrase.  Is there a name for this phenomenon? Is it correlated with any other geographic or cultural groupings?  What criteria does standard English use to deny the use of an indirect object in these sentences?

I think these sentences usually use transitive verbs, but it seems like for some verbs, a direct object is OK, but not an indirect object.  My hypothesis is that it is because these are stative (not action) verbs, but I am not certain.

Examples:

> Here is a pan to cook you some eggs. (Standard: Here is a pan for you to cook some eggs.)
>
> I have you a present.  (Standard:  I have a present for you.)

Comment: It doesn't strike me as odd, but I'm from the South. Your first example is actually mite likely a reflexive pronoun (*here's a pan for you to cook yourself some eggs*) but we frequently drop the "self" part from them. Your second one sounds off to me. It needs more information to sound natural, like *I have you a gift right here / in my car / waiting outside*

Comment: Also... Cook isn't stative

Comment: It's about verbs, not pronouns. This is using verbs with a valency different from the standard usage.

Comment: More precisely it's about constructions: this looks like an extension of the normal English ditransitive construction (as in "Joe cooked Sally some eggs").